# connection : didReceiveData is not called

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsurlconnection, xcode4.3

I am having a problem in NSURLConnection. My didRecieveData method is not being called . I dont know what's the problem. I also went through almost all the previous problems but nothing seems to solve.

Please help me out.
This is my code.

```
      -(void)gettheJSONdata
     {
           NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:_serverAddress cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];

           [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

           NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

          NSLog(@"This is displayed");
     }

     -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
     {
           NSLog(@"This is not displayed.");
           AppAppDelegate *JSONdata = (AppAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

           JSONdata.userloginJSONdata = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:data];

           NSError *error;

          _result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONdata.userloginJSONdata options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

           NSString *test = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
           NSLog(@"Json data : %@",test);
     }

     -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*) connection
     {
           AppAppDelegate *resultofJSONdata = (AppAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

           resultofJSONdata.JSONdataresult = _result;
      }
```

Comment: Did you add the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol to you header file?

Comment: Yup...
@interface Backbone : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDelegate>

This way...

Comment: The protocol in the header file does not impact anything. The real question is, was the delegate of the NSURLConnection set? I'm assuming it was... since I'm guessing the connectionDidFinishedLoading: gets hit, right?

Comment: No , the connectionDidFinishLoading is also not called.

Comment: Try logging connection in your gettheJSONdata method to make sure it isn't nil.

Comment: nops.. it is not nil..
logging gave me : <NSURLConnection: 0x7929010>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem.
I didnt synthesize the JSONdataresult.

I didn't realise that this could cause a problem with NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't start the request. You need:

```
[connection start];
```

or

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Edit: My comment below had the incorrect method name. Try implementing both:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

and

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

And see if either of those are being hit.

Comment: Update your post with the new code, because this is definitely a problem with your code. Also implement the connectionDidStart: delegate method and check to see if that one is hit. Because your request could be failing, which wouldn't hit either of the methods you posted.

Comment: Is there any method like connectionDidStart: ???
I have never seen it.
Could you send me the syntax..

Comment: Sorry, that was off the top of my head. I just updated my answer, refer to that. connection:didReceiveResponse: is what is called when (per the documentation) "the connection has received sufficient data to construct the URL response for its request", which is what I was thinking of when I posted that comment.

Comment: No problem . 
I tried using connection:DidRecieveResponse : method but that also is not called.

Comment: Is the first 'd' in "Did" lowercased? Did you implement the connection:didFailWithError: as well?

Comment: I tried both 'd' and 'D' but no effect and connection:didfailwitherror is also not being called.

Comment: Are you sure the `NSURLConnection` object is initializing correctly? As in it is not nil?   If you're not receiving any of the delegates, and you are definitely calling `start`, it seems more plausible.

Comment: 10 seconds is pretty low as a timeoutInterval... but you should get the connection:didFailWithError: called in that case

Answer (score 0):

in my case header was No connection didReceiveData not getting called ,be sure to add authorisation  if it is required for request,

```
    [urlRequest setValue:[UserContext sharedInstance].requesthandler.reqHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```