# always! On iOS 6.0 and on 3G network NSURLConnection is getting failed with didFailWithError?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4, ios6, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I checked on stackOverFlow and other, that on `didReceiveData:, didReceiveResponse:` are available with NSURLConnectionDataDelegate upon Version 4.3. From version 2.3 to 4.3 they are available in NSURLConnectionDelegate.

Have a look at these:

[http://stackoverflow.com:(10937215)connection-didreceivedata-is-not-called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937215/connection-didreceivedata-is-not-called)

[http://stackoverflow.com:(7862316) ios5 nsurlconnection methods deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862316/ios5-nsurlconnection-methods-deprecated)

By checking SDK version we could inherit a specific class I guess, I haven't tested. But but can be achieved I guess.

But problem is that I am running on iOS 6.0 and on 3G network, then its getting failed with timeout error all the time. On WIFI, `didReceiveData:` is getting called even if I use NSURLConnectionDelegate. Felt little strange.

In my class which extends NSURLConnectionDelegate, these are the methods to look at.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Private didReceiveResponse - %d", [response statusCode]);

    if([response statusCode] == 200)
        connectionstatus = YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    self.connectionstatus = YES;

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection 
{
    NSLog(@"Private connectionDidFinishLoading");

    self.connectionstatus = NO;
    [self reinitConnection];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    self.connectionstatus = NO;
    self.connection= nil;
}


- (void) reinitConnection
{
    self.connectionstatus = YES;
    connectionCount++;
    NSString* urlS = @“VALID url”; //Such as http://google.com
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlS];
    self.req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0];
    NSString *appstring =[httpreq appendMyParamsPost:req];
    [req setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@",[url absoluteString],appstring]]];

    NSString* authValue = @“SomeValue”,
    [req addValue:@"application/vnd.gupshup.privatechat-v1+json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req addValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [self.connection cancel];
    self.connection = nil;
    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}
```

Any issues? Why is it specifically on 3G though there are issues of method shuffle at SDK level, where in, it has to happen on WIFI as well?

Thanks in advance.
Venkatarao

Comment: I doubt that your problem has anything to do with `didReceiveData:` or where it's declared or documented. The changes Apple made are a bit confusing but it has always been reliably working and it's always been upward and downward compatible. It rather looks as if you indeed have a general network problem when connecting from your phone to the server.

Comment: Then safari or other HTTP requests on my app should fail to get data. They are working fine except this connection instance.

Comment: You have set the timeout to 20 seconds. Is this sufficient for the request to be fully processed and transmitted over 3G? (Prior to iOS 6, the timeout was ignored.)

Comment: I am sorry! Thanks for noticing that. I checked that as well by putting time out to 120 secs (max). But no help.